# Link IBM i (AS/400) to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ibm-midrange

I have tried linking an AS/400 to SQL Server using the following drivers: "IBM DB2 for i IBMDASQL OLE DB Provider", "IBM DB2 for i IBMDA400 OLE DB Provider", and "IBM DB2 for i IBMDARLA OLE DB Provider". The connections test successful, but when I run this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM AS400.MyCatalog.SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM OpenQuery(AS400, 'SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS');
```

I get the following error:

> OLE DB provider "IBMDARLA" for linked server "AS400" returned message "CPF4326: Commitment definition *N not valid for open of SQLCOLUMNS.".
>
> Msg 7306, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Cannot open the table "Tmxloop.SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS" from OLE DB provider "IBMDARLA" for linked server "AS400".
>
> Completion time: 2022-03-29T10:46:59.3399022-04:00

How do I get at least one of the connections to accept my SQL queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Driver

`"IBM DB2 for i IBMDASQL OLE DB Provider"`

Under Providers update driver "`IBMDASQL`" to "`Allow inprocess`"

Now SQL will work

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM AS400.MyCatalog.SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS
```

Comment: Please flag this post as answered.

Comment: @PoC I will, sorry I can't yet since I answered my own question